# Divergent Series Properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Given $a_n$ a sequence of positive real numbers and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k \rightarrow \infty
$$

Is it necessarily true that

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(a_k)(k^{1+\epsilon})\rightarrow \infty
$$

for any positive real $\epsilon$?

It is true for the prime harmonic series, but I'm curious if it is true in general. It feels like it is not but I can't put together a good counter example and was looking for some help. If $a_n$ is strictly decreasing, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general. Consider the sequence $$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{k}~~~~~~\text{$k$ even}\\\frac{1}{k^2}~~~~~\text{$k$ odd}\end{cases}$$
Then we have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\infty$ but for every $0<\varepsilon<1$ we have $a_kk^{1+\varepsilon}\not\to\infty$.
However, notice that in this example we at least have $$\limsup_{k\to\infty}a_kk^{1+\varepsilon}=\infty$$
And this will be true in general. (proof: If $\limsup_{k\to\infty}a_kk^{1+\varepsilon}<\infty$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ there is a constant $M$ such that $a_k\leq \frac{M}{k^{1+\varepsilon}}$ for all $k$, hence $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k<\infty$ by the comparison test)

Atm I am not sure about the last part if $a_k$ is strictly decreasing, maybe I will update later or someone else can post an answer to that.